# does Any == Object

Tags: kotlin

The following code in kotlin:

```
Any().javaClass
```

Has value of `java.lang.Object`. Does that mean `Any` and `Object` are the same class? What are their relations?

Comment: Does **Any** support generics?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

No.

From the [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html)
(Emphasis mine)

> All classes in Kotlin have a common superclass `Any`, that is a default 
>   super for a class with no supertypes declared:
>
> `class Example // Implicitly inherits from Any`
>
> **`Any` is not `java.lang.Object`**; in particular, it does not have any 
>   members other than `equals()`, `hashCode()` and `toString()`. Please 
>   consult the Java interoperability section for more details.

Further, from the section on mapped types we find:

> Kotlin treats some Java types specially. Such types are not loaded from 
>   Java “as is”, but are mapped to corresponding Kotlin types. The mapping 
>   only matters at compile time, the runtime representation remains 
>   unchanged. Java’s primitive types are mapped to corresponding Kotlin 
>   types (keeping platform types in mind):
>
> ...
>
> `java.lang.Object`    `kotlin.Any!`

This says that at **runtime** `java.lang.Object` and `kotlin.Any!` are treated the same. But the `!` also means that the type is a platform type, which has implication with respect to disabling null checks etc.

> Any reference in Java may be null, which makes Kotlin’s requirements of 
>   strict null-safety impractical for objects coming from Java. Types of 
>   Java declarations are treated specially in Kotlin and called platform 
>   types. Null-checks are relaxed for such types, so that safety guarantees 
>   for them are the same as in Java (see more below).
>
> ...
>
> When we call methods on variables of platform types, Kotlin does not 
>   issue nullability errors at compile time, but the call may fail at 
>   runtime, because of a null-pointer exception or an assertion that Kotlin 
>   generates to prevent nulls from propagating:

Comment: e.i. consult this one: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types

Comment: can you explain the difference between them and why does java class of any is object?

Comment: `Kotlin generates to prevent nulls from propagating` 

propagting to?

Answer (score 15):

Kotlin compiler treats `kotlin.Any` and `java.lang.Object` as two different *types*, but at runtime they are represented with the same `java.lang.Object` *class*.

`javaClass` property returns the runtime class of an instance, so that's why you get the same `java.lang.Object` class in both cases.

There are also other types which are different at compile time, but the same at runtime; they are listed in the [Mapped types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types) section of the documentation.

Comment: Any does not declare wait(), notify(), notifyAll() which makes it impossible to use as a lock as opposed to a regular Java object.

Comment: @dkarmazi You can cast it to `java.lang.Object`, and then you'll be able to call these methods on it.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, there is no `java.lang.Object` in aspect of Kotlin lang, so you certainly cannot say `Any` is `Object`. You can only say `Any` takes the place of `Object` in Kotlin.

Comment: You can also cast to **Any** to **Object**

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly the same. It just blocks the attributes that Kotlin doesn't want：

```
fun main() {
    val any = Any()//java Object
    val obj = Object()//java Object
    println(any::class)//Object class
    println(obj::class)//Object class
}
```

smali：

```
fun test(aaaaa: Any) {
}
```

```
  public final static test(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (visible)
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (invisible)
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 0
   L0
    ALOAD 0
    LDC "aaaaa"
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 4 L1
    RETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE aaaaa Ljava/lang/Object; L0 L2 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  @Lkotlin/Metadata;(mv={1, 4, 2}, bv={1, 0, 3}, k=2, d1={"\u0000\u000e\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0000\u001a\u000e\u0010\u0000\u001a\u00020\u00012\u0006\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u0003\u00a8\u0006\u0004"}, d2={"test", "", "aaaaa", "", "SPWrapper.app"})
  // compiled from: T.kt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`"Any"` is the analogue of `java.lang.Object`: a superclass of all classes in Kotlin.

Comment: In what way is it an `analogue`?  It is a bit different at compile time...