# Kotlin classes cannot be found when reflecting filepaths to source directories or jars

Tags: reflection, jar, kotlin, classloader

===Update: Using org.reflections:reflections:0.9.11

Looking to use the following line to pull a list of class names from Kotlin source...

```
Reflections.getSubTypesOf(Any::class.java)
```

However I receive a message that Kotlin class files aren't being seen when I run the following script...

```
val classLoader = URLClassLoader(this.getDirectoryUrls(), null)
println("retrieved class loader")

val config = getConfig(classLoader)
println("retrieved source config")

val reflections = Reflections(config)
println("retrieved reflections")

// For 3 paths: Reflections took 3 ms to scan 3 urls, producing 0 keys and 0 values
```

=== Update: The 3 urls added by "getDirectoryUrls()" are directories containing kotlin class source files.

Below is my config... ideas?

```
private fun getConfig(classLoader: ClassLoader): ConfigurationBuilder {
    val config = ConfigurationBuilder().setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoader))
    //                .setScanners(SubTypesScanner(false), ResourcesScanner())

    if (!packagePath.isNullOrBlank()){
        System.out.println("looking in package [$packagePath]")
        config.filterInputsBy(FilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder.prefix(packagePath)))
    }

    config.addClassLoader(classLoader)
    config.setScanners(SubTypesScanner(), TypeAnnotationsScanner())

    return config
}
```

Comment: You should mention which reflection library you used. What does `getDirectoryUrls()` return?

Comment: details added as requested. See above...

Answer (score 0):

Setting [`SubTypesScanner(false)`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.reflections/reflections/0.9.10/org/reflections/scanners/SubTypesScanner.html#SubTypesScanner-boolean-) seems to be required to get any types with `getSubTypesOf(Any::class.java)` (that parameter itself stands for `excludeObjectClass`). Looking at the bytecode of Kotlin classes you immediately see, that they are actually looking the same as Java classes. There is no `Any`-superclass there. Note that Kotlins `Any` is actually also in other means very similar to Javas `Object` (but not the same, check also the following [answer to  'does Any == Object'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38761552/6202869)). So, we need to include the `Object`-class when scanning for subtypes of `Any` (i.e. `excludeObjectClass=false`).

Another problem could be the setup of your `URL` array. I just used the following to setup the reflections util:

```
val reflections = Reflections(ConfigurationBuilder()
            .addUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("my.test.package"))
            .setScanners(TypeAnnotationsScanner(), SubTypesScanner(false)))
```

which will resolve all matching subtypes and will return subtypes also for `Any`.

```
reflections.getSubTypesOf(MyCustomSuperType::class.java).forEach(::println)
reflections.getSubTypesOf(Any::class.java).forEach(::println)
```

Analysing further: you mention "Kotlin class ***source*** files"... if that means you are pointing to the directory containing the `.kt`-files, then that is probably your problem. Try to use the directory which contains the `.class`-files instead. Moreover, ensure that the classes are on the classpath.

Maybe you know already, maybe not? Note also that if you have a (classes) directory, say `/sample/directory`, which is on the classpath and which contains a package, say `org.example` (which corresponds to the folder structure `org/example` or full path `/sample/directory/org/example`) then you must ensure that you add an `URL` similar to the following:

```
 YourClass::class.java.classLoader.getResource("")
```

and not:

```
 YourClass::class.java.classLoader.getResource("org.example")
 // nor:
 YourClass::class.java.classLoader.getResource("org/example")
```

You basically require the "base" directory (in the example `/sample/directory` or from the view of the classloader just `""`)) where to lookup the packages and not the package itself. If you would supply one of the latter `URL`s, only classes that are in the default package (within `/sample/directory/org/example`) would actually be found, which however is a rather uncommon setup.

Comment: while SubTypesScanner(false) I've already tried it (you can see it commented out in the comments). Both getSubTypesOf Any and Object do not return any reflections. I've also tried several different combinations of loading packages onto the classpath (including package location and lookup against specific jars I know have objects on classpath). In the end I decided to bypasses adding complexity of looking at packages or jars and went right to directories containing class files to rule out not putting something in a jar. This is the reason I used the example above.

Comment: It might sound like a chore but working in the context of the above example was done for a reason. I'm trying to get to the bottom of why I can't even reflect against a directory. If you can reproduce a result using the example above let me know.

Comment: Hmmm.. yeah, sorry.. I tend to ignore commented out code all the time ;-) So did I understand you correctly? You want to load any folder (e.g. one that isn't on the classpath?)? Will try your exact example tomorrow, but show also one of the URLs and maybe also the contained package..

Comment: Added some more analysis to the answer... you may continue reading from "Analysing further"... Note that `SubTypesScanner(false)` is required to return appropriate types when using `getSubTypesOf(Any::class.java)`. As long as you deal with class files (preferably on the classpath) the scanning should be no problem.