# Any object that extends specified class as parameter in function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm building base activity where I have a method to init `RecyclerView`.
I want this method to have parameter which is an object/class which **extends**`PagedListAdapter<object, object extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.

Let's say I have class `myAdapter` which extends `PagedListAdapter<myDataObject, myAdapter.ViewHolder>` and I want to attach `myAdapter` as adapter in `RecyclerView` using my method:

from **Activity:**

```
fun foo() = initRecyclerView(myAdapter())
```

and then in my **base**:

```
protected fun initRecyclerView(mAdapter: Class<out PagedListAdapter<Any, out RecyclerView.ViewHolder>>) {
    if (mRecyclerView?.layoutManager == null)
        mRecyclerView?.layoutManager = component.linearLayoutManager
    if (mRecyclerView?.adapter == null)
        mRecyclerView?.adapter = mAdapter
}
```

but I'm getting `Type mismatch`:
Required: `(RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>?..RecyclerView.Adapter<*>?)`
Found: `Class<out PagedListAdapter<Any, out RecyclerView.ViewHolder>>`

How do I fix it to make this method "universal", to accept any type that extends `PagedListAdapter<object, any extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder>`?

Comment: Have look  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38761552/5110595)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your paramter is `Class<out PagedListAdapter<Any, out RecyclerView.ViewHolder>>` which is instance of class `java.lang.Class`, but you want instance of `PagedListAdapter` like this:

```
protected fun initRecyclerView(mAdapter: PagedListAdapter<out Any, out RecyclerView.ViewHolder>) {
    if (mRecyclerView?.layoutManager == null)
        mRecyclerView?.layoutManager = component.linearLayoutManager
    if (mRecyclerView?.adapter == null)
        mRecyclerView?.adapter = mAdapter
}
```