# Is kotlin.String really a java.lang.String?

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm interested to know how `kotlin.String` is implemented, since it reports itself as a `java.lang.String`, yet has more methods available (according to `ki` autocompletion) even accounting for extension methods:

```
[34] kotlin.String().javaClass
res17: Class<String> = class java.lang.String

[35] "10".javaClass
res18: Class<String> = class java.lang.String

[36] "10".toLong()
res19: Long = 10

[37] java.lang.String("10").javaClass
res20: Class<String> = class java.lang.String

[38] java.lang.String("10").toLong()
ERROR Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is 
applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline fun String.toLong(): Long defined in kotlin.text
public inline fun String.toLong(radix: Int): Long defined in 
kotlin.text (Line_39.kts:1:24)
```

Is `kotlin.String` really a `java.lang.String`?

Comment: Kotlin does a lot of magic to add behavior to Java APIs.

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin supports adding functionality to classes without extending the class, via extensions:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html

You can see String.toLong is added along with many other extensions to base Java classes via the kotlin.text package here:
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/

Comment: Can you explain why `java.lang.String("10").toLong()` fails, as shown in my original example?

Comment: You are subverting the Java-to-Kotlin mapped type by specifically declaring the Java type.

Comment: I think it is more accurate to say the `toLong` extension method is written for `kotlin.String` and not `java.lang.String`. AFAICT, those extensions are not added to the base Java classes. Doing so would make sense if you want to support multiple platforms.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the other comments posted here, it looks like `kotlin.String` is *not* a `java.lang.String`, but it *does* compile to one, according to the [java/kotlin type mapping](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#mapped-types). So even though the runtime class is the same, the compiler treats them differently. Since the [`toLong` extension method is implemented on kotlin.String](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/92d200e093c693b3c06e53a39e0b0973b84c7ec5/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/text/StringNumberConversionsJVM.kt#L115), it is not available for `java.lang.String`.

You can pull the same trick in reverse:

```
[71] fun java.lang.String.zero(): Long = 0
[72] java.lang.String().zero()
res36: Long = 0
```

but this extension method is not available for a `kotlin.String`, even though it compiles to a `java.lang.String`.

```
[73] "kotlin string".javaClass
res37: Class<String> = class java.lang.String
[74] "kotlin string".zero()
ERROR Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public final fun String.zero(): Long defined in Line_72 (Line_75.kts:1:17)
```

To further complicate the matter, a `java.lang.String` is normally loaded as a `kotlin.String` unless you give the fully qualified name.

```
[0] java.lang.String("12345").toLong()
ERROR Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline fun String.toLong(): Long defined in kotlin.text
public inline fun String.toLong(radix: Int): Long defined in kotlin.text (Line_1.kts:1:27)

[1] java.lang.String("12345").substring(0).toLong()
res0: Long = 12345
```

So the answer is no, a `kotlin.String` is not a `java.lang.String`. They are interoperable because they compile to the same class, but the compiler still distinguishes between them.

Related question: [does Any == Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761021/does-any-object)